# Improving jquery select speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, cpu-speed

I have this code which manipulates the asp.net treeview html code.

This code gets run frequently, so its important that it runs as fast as possible.

I want to learn more about jquery selectors and improving its speed. So far I was able to get this code myself.

Some things I am not sure about is if you want the third child element, do I use `[2]` or `.eq(2)` or `:nth-child(2)`? Also what if I use `$` to select something that was from an array of selected stuff, is this necessary, or is it already selected?

Does anyone know any tricks or hints I can do to improve my jquery select efficiency?

Thanks.

```
function showResultsOnTreeview(treeviewID, filenameDictionary) {
    var sectionNodes = $("#" + treeviewID + " > table");
    var numOfSections = sectionNodes.length;
    var i, j, sectionName, divContainer, itemNodes, numOfItems, itemName, itemTag, itemPath;

    for (i = 0; i < numOfSections; i += 1) {
        sectionName = $(sectionNodes[i]).text();
        divContainer = $(sectionNodes[i]).next('div');
        divContainer.hide();
        itemNodes = $('table', divContainer);
        numOfItems = itemNodes.length;
        for (j = 0; j < numOfItems; j += 1) {
            itemTag = $('td', $(itemNodes[j])).eq(2);
            itemTag.removeClass('treeViewResult');
            itemName = getNameFromItem($(itemNodes[j]).text());
            itemPath = filenameDictionary[itemName];
            if (itemPath != null) {
                if (itemPath.indexOf(sectionName + "/" + itemName) != -1) {
                    itemTag.addClass('treeViewResult');
                    divContainer.show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @epascarello: I don't even know how I would use this, as this is coming from a asp.net solution on a private Microsoft sharepoint environment.

Comment: For sure cache the objects as much as possible, such as `var sect =  $(sectionNodes[i]);`

Comment: so if I do this $(X), and this gives me an array of size 5 for example, do I need to do $(X[0]) or is X[0] already selected?

Comment: You do not know how to make simple test cases of different selectors? Add some HTML and test to see what selection runs the fastest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some optimisation you can do. The first on is for sure to use `.eq()` instead of `[]`. Like here, you hare creating a jQuery object :

```
var sectionNodes = $("#" + treeviewID + " > table");
```

But then later, you do this :

```
sectionName = $(sectionNodes[i]).text();
divContainer = $(sectionNodes[i]).next('div');
```

Here you are creating 2 more, unneeded, jquery object, you could just do this :

```
sectionName = sectionNodes.eq(i).text();
divContainer = sectionName.next('div');
```

Then, i do't know if you have a different way to do it, but if you can remove the "loop in a loop", that would be great.

After, instead of using context selectore (`$('selector', $element)`), use find. Context use find so it will reduce the number of function calls. Take this line for example :

```
 $('td', $(itemNodes[j])).eq(2)
```

You are creating 2 jQuery object when you can do the same without an extra object and could use `.find()`:

```
itemTag = itemNodes.eq(j).find('td').eq(2);
```

Basicly, use `.find()` instead of context and avoid creating unneeded jQuery object. Hope that will help.

Comment: Is this ok to use: `itemTag = curItem.find('td:nth-child(3)');` or should I use `.eq(2)`? It feels like if I use `eq`, then it will get all the objects, then get the nth one from that. But if I use nth-child, then I will only get 1 element.

Comment: That was an interesting question. I made a jsperf (http://jsperf.com/nth-child-vs-eq-56) and it turn out that `eq` is faster. My guess would be that `nth-child` use condition behind the code to calculate the child position (looping through every element in the jquery object) while `.eq()` is directly going to the index (no loop).